# GEF - arrow key drag and drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, eclipse-gef

I am working on a software platform which already uses GEF for drag and drop support, but this only enables the dragging by mouse. Is there any way to extend this feature so that it is possible to drag a model element using the arrow keys ? I can't seem to find an answer to  this. Thank you !

PS : I think changeboundsrequest should be a focus point in solving this.

Comment: gef is what I wrote in the first place. Still thanks for suggestion.

Comment: When you say "drag" you mean "move", right?